# Quadratic equation rearranging

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to turn the equation L=12/x + x into a quadratic forumla to solve. i have been given the answers of 0.619m 0r 19.38m if L = 20m

what iv go so far

0= 12/x + x -20
but i dont know how to turn 12/x to a x^2 value

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the equation by $x$ and you'll get the polynomial you want.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
L &= \dfrac{12}{x} + x \\
Lx &= 12 + x^2 & (\text{multiplying both sides by x}) \\
x^2 + 12 - Lx &= 0 \\
\\
\text{For L = 20,} \\
x^2 - 20x + 12 &= 0 \\
\\
\text{Solving using the quadratic formula} \\
x = 0.619 \text{ or } x = 19.380 & \text{as required}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oops, sorry just realized this question is 8 months old!

Comment: How did you happen to come across such an old question? It's funny.

Comment: Hah! It was the top item in the related list on the sidebar while I was asking a new question.